# I got validation loss of 1.86, how should I reduce it?

Tags: tensorflow

[graph of my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lDgA.png)
I ran a model to classify two different types of images and I got a val_loss of 1.875 and learning rate was 1e-3 for 600 images what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

From the graph you provided it looks like your model is overfitting since about epoch 20. This makes sense since you only have 600 images.

I would suggest you take a closer look at the graph for the first epochs, and stop training earlier to save the model with the lowest validation loss. Data augmentation might help delay the onset of overfitting as well.